# detecting when a Google maps InfoWindow will cause the map to pan

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When a user clicks a marker to open an InfoWindow, I need to synchronize something elsewhere on the web page.  If opening the InfoWindow leaves the the map in place, I want to do this synchronization right away.  On the other hand, if it causes an animated pan of the map, I want to wait until later to do the synchronization (that is, following a fetch of new marker items that gets triggered in the "idle" event).

Anyway, the point is that I need to somehow be able to detect when opening the infowindow is going to trigger an animated map pan.  Or, at least be able to detect when an animation is in progress.

Using api v3.

Comment: Just thinking.Maybe on the marker click event you can start a timer and wait until the map is idle.

Comment: The problem with that is that in some cases, there will not be an idle that follows (if opening the info window doesn't cause the map to be  moved).  I managed to do what I want with a combination of timer, processing the "center_changed" event, and idle... but it's messy and hackish.